# Silverlight Docking Control

Tags: silverlight, docking

I wanna do Docking control at run time, and set a splitter between the docked control and the others exactly like Visual Studio. I don't know what is the best option, I'm thinking about: changing it's grid row the control where (when dock the control to bottom change the control to the bottom row of the main grid), I tried to change the control's row from 0 to 1, the control then disappeared??!!

Any Help???

Thanks

Comment: Please give us a little code.

Answer (score 0):

In the silverlight toolkit you have a DockPanel that works kinda like "Forms".  But everything is Xaml though :).

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528

If you are new to Silverlight it may be a little difficult to understand the Grid control at first (I went through that myself), but it is really powerfull and flexible.  Take the time to clearly understand all its features.  I personnally never use the DockPanel.

Comment: I need to Dock control at run time, and set a splitter between the docked control and the others like Visual Studio